# Can anyone please provide me the procedure for Narasimha Puja, in English? (Not Lakshmi Narasimha)

Tags: puja, narasimha

Can anyone tell me Narasimha Puja Vidhi for Narasimha Jayanti?

Comment: well I have a narasimha temple near me.Let me ask

Comment: @Akash.B please do ask and tell me. It would be so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What references are you looking for? Is it acceptable if I share what is done practically even though the full reasons are not known?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the indication in the brackets? It's not clear.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I was looking for the procedure for Sri Narasimha Puja, also known as Puja Vidhi. In the brackets I meant that I need the specifications of a normal Narasimha posture. The Ugra Roopa. Not Lakshmi Narasimha which is calm and gentle. Both the forms have different styles of worship.

Comment: Oh ok, I can't help then - I don't know how to worship Ugra Roopam. btw I think one has to be careful when doing sankalpam with UgraPurusha, I guess you already knew that?

Comment: We have to be careful doing everything, but that precise meticulous things apply for people who do it for worldly gains. You are right though. But if anyone is doing it solely for Bhakti, then everything is fine. Bhakti transcends all dimensions and aims directly for the Lord.